# How to take user input In Qt with image background Widget view?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I want the user to enter a password to starts the Qt application. To take the input from the user I am using the QInputDialog widget.

The problem is I doesn't know how to add this widget on the above of some image showing window widget, this is my code

```
 bool ok;
 QString text = QInputDialog::getText(this, 
 tr("QInputDialog::getText()"),tr("Enter the password:"), 
 QLineEdit::password,"Qt-application", &ok);

 if (ok && !text.isEmpty())
     textLabel->setText(text);
```

The above-used method is looking very casual, can anybody share the sample code to get the password from the user so it looks something good with the proper size and alignment adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't satisfied with the way QInputDialog looks, why don't you use the form designer in Qt Creator to make your own fancy looking password input dialog?

In Qt Creator, select `File` -> `New File or Project`. Then choose the `Qt` template under `Files and Classes` and then select `Qt Designer Form Class`. From there, go through the wizard and it'll create an empty dialog for you (*.ui). Open the .UI file, then you can drag 'n drop your desired widgets, set properties, configure layout, etc...